# octave use vector as columns index for a matrix

Tags: matrix, vector, indexing, octave

I've a vector `y = [1; 1; 2; 3]` and a matrix `Y = zeros(4, 3)`.
I need to set to `1` the columns in `Y` that corresponds to values of the vector `y`. i.e.

```
Y = [1, 0, 0; 1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; 0, 0, 1]
```

Y(y) or Y(:, y) does not give me the result I need!

Any idea how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert those columns indices into linear indices.  You do it like so:

```
octave:1> A = zeros (4, 3);
octave:2> c_sub = [1, 1, 2, 3];
octave:3> ind = sub2ind (size (A), 1:rows(A), c_sub)
ind =

    1    2    7   12
octave:4> A(ind) = 1
A =

   1   0   0
   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1
```

However, if your matrix is that sparse, do create a proper sparse matrix:

```
octave:4> sparse (1:4, c_sub, 1, 4, 3)
ans =

Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 4, cols = 3, nnz = 4 [33%])

  (1, 1) ->  1
  (2, 1) ->  1
  (3, 2) ->  1
  (4, 3) ->  1
```

and maybe consider using a logical matrix (use `false` instead of `zeros` and `true` instead of `1`.

Comment: where the `c_sub` comes from? I'm having `error: 'c_sub' undefined near line 1 column 37`!

Comment: @bachr `c_sub` is `y.'` from your question, `A` in carandraugs answer is your `Y`